# does firebase-UI for cloud Firestore on android stopListening() actually stops listening to data from firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I wanted to implement stopListening() when the data reaches certain value, The [Documentation](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/firestore/readme) clearly states

> the stopListening() call freezes the data in the RecyclerView and prevents any future loading of data pages

I implement it on my recyclerview to stopListening() on RecyclerViewAddOnScrollListener,

```
       override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            val totalItem = adapter?.itemCount ?: 0

            if (totalItem > itemMax && dy > 0){
                adapter?.stopListening()
                Log.d(MusimArsipFragment::class.java.name, "item didapat = " + adapter?.itemCount)}

        }
```

I have also tried to manually stop it by implementing a button to implement stopListening() the data, but for some reason neither worked! the data keep on loading when I am at the bottom of the page, I have tried to delete cache in case it loads the data from cache and a lot of trial and Error, because of that I am almost certain that it's always getting data from firestore. Am I having a brain-freeze here and the solution is actually really simple? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The FirebaseUI libraries are all open-source, so if you go to the [`FirebaseUI-Android` Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), you can see that [`FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.stopListening`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4455f411e3605743bb4511d1a75cda7f398bc399/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L59-L62) is implemented as:

```
public void stopListening() {
    mSnapshots.removeChangeEventListener(this);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Which in turn leads to [`BaseObservableSnapshotArray.removeChangeEventListener`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4455f411e3605743bb4511d1a75cda7f398bc399/common/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/common/BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java#L108-L116):

```
public void removeChangeEventListener(@NonNull L listener) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(listener);

    boolean wasListening = isListening();

    mListeners.remove(listener);

    if (!isListening() && wasListening) { onDestroy(); }
}
```

Which then finally leads to [`FirestoreArray.onDestroy`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/4455f411e3605743bb4511d1a75cda7f398bc399/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreArray.java#L67-L71):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mRegistration = mQuery.addSnapshotListener(mMetadataChanges, this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRegistration.remove();
    mRegistration = null;
}
```

And if you look carefully, you'll see that this is precisely how the Firestore documentation says that you should [remove listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java_10).

Keep in mind though that this only stops the listener from receiving further updates. It will still continue processing data it has already received.
So yeah, it looks like calling `stopListening` *does* really unregister the listener from Firestore. You may be seeing the effects of that, although I can't say from just the code you shared.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have a swipe refresh in onLoadingStateChange and it only refresh when it's getting data and not when I've stoppedListening(). and from that I know it actually stopped LoadingMore, so it definitely did something. But the data keeps on loading. I don't want to bother people with trivial code hence the lack of code. I'll update the post if I have found the problem.